# class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableData

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Here is my code below.

```
#import "PhotoGalleryTableViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define kPhotoGalleryURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/2v35aqn0?apikey=xgp4nU6xA9UcBWSe0MIHcBVbAWz5v4wR"]


@interface PhotoGalleryTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *photoGallery;

@end

@implementation PhotoGalleryTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kPhotoGalleryURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedGalleryData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

-(void)fetchedGalleryData:(NSData *)galleryResponseData {
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:galleryResponseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
NSArray *myPhotoGallery = [[json objectForKey:@"results"]objectForKey:@"collection1"];
myPhotoGallery = self.photoGallery;
NSLog(@"%@", self.photoGallery);
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.photoGallery count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"galleryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"galleryCell"];
}

NSDictionary *galleries = [self.photoGallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *description = [[galleries objectForKey:@"description"] objectForKey:@"text"];
NSMutableString *images = [[galleries objectForKey:@"photo"] objectForKey:@"src"];

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:images];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

cell.textLabel.text = description;
cell.imageView.image = img;


return cell;
}
@end
```

When I ran the app I got this Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableData.'in my console. And also the console does not display the photoGallery array.

I already declared kBgQueue in my appdelegate.h file and imported it. I have another very similar view controller and everything works fine in that one.

Thank you in advance, and sorry for being such a burden.

Comment: myPhotoGallery = self.photoGallery;  should be  self.photoGallery=myPhotoGallery;

Comment: There is no mention of `tableData` in the code you've posted.

Comment: Look at the outlets inspector in Interface Builder. You can get this sort of error if the scene has an IBOutlet hooked up to one of it's controls (in this case, an `IBOutlet` called `tableData`), but not have any such `IBOutlet` defined in your .m file. This commonly happens if you hook up an `IBOutlet`, but then later rename it, neglecting to update it in IB, too.

Comment: @adnan I changed it but i m still getting the same exception error

Comment: @Rob But i don't have any IBOutlets in this view controller

Comment: Also, do i need to add prototype cell in this case?

Comment: Well, you have `tableData` reference somewhere, and if you don't see it in your source code, the only other place it's typically found is the storyboard/NIB.